# Where COM and OLE are used in 2019?

Tags: c++, windows, com

I'm not very familiar with COM. So I wonder if it's not dead, considering there's *.Net*.

Were is COM still used? Is it used to implement parts of *.Net*?

As far as I know *MS Office* is based on OLE. Do they still use OLE?

It seems like it's the underlying technology for many things, and everything what's claimed to replace COM is just a wrapper. Is it so?

Comment: No. COM is not dead, for example Windows Shell is still used COM. Also UI Automation.

Comment: The whole Windows Runtime is build using COM conventions.

Comment: COM stays in Microsoft's toolbox to get arbitrary languages to use their C++ code.  Including the new stuff, UWP is entirely COM at its core.  There's no other decent way to get, say, a Javascript program to call a C++ or C# function.  Well hidden btw, the "language projection" feature makes it look easy and programmers rarely realize they use COM.  Until it goes wrong anyway.  OLE is quite dead, it was hardest to remove completely from Office.

Comment: OLE is still alive. Not as active as it used to be. If you paste a picture into Word or Excel, you're using OLE. Nothing has been deprecated--although Word and Excel don't seem to like to support in place editing anymore.